# Passing JSON data to Laravel view without casting in the model

Tags: json, laravel

I have this function that fetches data from a table, paginates the data, and passes it to the view:

```
public function job_requests(){
        
        $orders = DB::table('orders')
                    ->select('id','order_data','order_status')
                    ->paginate(5);
        
        return view('autorepair/mechanics/job_requests',compact('orders'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
            
    }
```

The column `order_data` contains data of the following format:

```
{
    "personal_data": {
        "email": "info@info.com",
        "telephone_number": "0999",
        "postal_address": "LON",
        "car_registration": "GB BHG"
    },
    "inperson_diagnostic": {
        "diagnostic_inspection": "67.30",
        "car_wont_start_inspection": "67.30",
        "plugin_diagnostic_inspection": "67.30"
    },
    "tyres": {
        "front_wheels": 1,
        "rear_wheels": 1,
        "wheel_width": 45,
        "wheel_profile": 1,
        "wheel_rim": 1,
        "speed_rating": "w",
        "final_price": 90
    },
    "servicing_and_mot": {
        "mot_with_collection_delivery": 75,
        "major_service": 304.52,
        "full_service": 203.45,
        "interim_service": "149.70",
        "vehicle_health_check": 50
    },
    "inspection_services": {
        "premium_prepurchase_inspection": 146.38,
        "standard_prepurchase_inspection": 104,
        "basic_prepurchase_inspection": 86.44
    },
    "repairs": {
        "ABS wheel speed sensor replacement": 964,
        "ABS pump replacement": 712,
        "Brake pedal switch replacement": 568,
        "Air conditioning regas (R1234yf Gas ONLY)": 469
    }
}
```

In my view, I have this:

```
@if(!$orders->isEmpty())
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Order Status</th>
            <th>Order Data</th>
            <th width="280px">Action</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach ($orders as $order)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ ++$i }}</td>
            <td>{{ $order->order_status }}</td>
            <td>{{ $order->order_data}}</td>
            <td>
   
                    <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ url('/view_product/' . $order->id) }}">Show</a>
    
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ url('/edit_product/' . $order->id ) }}">Accept</a>
                    

            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </table>
  @else
    <p>No orders yet.</p>  
  @endif
    {!! $orders->links() !!}
```

I can display the JSON data here `$order->order_data` but I would like to have it decoded first. How can I pass a decoded array sent to the view and be able to keep the pagination links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could decode it in the view.

Depending on the format of `order_data` that is actually passed to the view  (forgive me, I don't know off-hand how builder or eloquent retrieves jsonb type), but you can use dd() or gettype() in the view, to help identify what data type `order_data` is when delivered to the view):

- If the content comes into the view as a string, try `json_decode()` on the `order_data` value. I think you should be able to iterate over the result of that, if that is your intent.

Comment: Php is sneaky. All i had to do is `json_decode($order->order_data)->personal_data->email`

Comment: Sneaky x 3000. Glad you got it!